# reshape a numpy 1D array to a 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am having problems reshaping an numpy array from 1D to 3D.

I am reading a video file, 
then I am extracting the Face out of x number of frames, and store the face in a numpy array with its labels.

```
fps = 3
time_of_video = 10
x = 0
face_size = 128

images = []
labels = []

for original_name, filename, label in tqdm(zip(train_sample_metadata['original'], train_sample_metadata['filename'], train_sample_metadata['label'])):

...

        video_1 = read_video(f'{base_path}/{filename}', fps*time_of_video)
        video_2 = read_video(f'{base_path}/{original_name}', fps*time_of_video)
        face_annotations = get_annotations(real_video)
        faces_1 = crop_faces(video_1, face_annotations, face_size)
        faces_2 = crop_faces(video_2, face_annotations, face_size)

        x = faces_1

        for ff, rf in zip(faces_1, faces_2):
            if np.array_equal(ff, rf):
                y.append(0)
            else:
                y.append(1)

        y = to_categorical(np.array(y), 2)

    images.append(x)
    labels.append(y)


images = np.array(images)
labels = np.array(labels)

images.shape, labels.shape
((400,), (400,))

images = images.reshape((images.shape[0] * images.shape[1], 128, 128, 3))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-af9e927f8a1c> in <module>
----> 1 images = images.reshape((images.shape[0] * images.shape[1], 299, 299, 3))

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: What do you expect `images.shape[1]` to be, given that `images` is 1-D?

Comment: Have you checked what's contained in `faces_1` before you store it in `x`? My guess is that it isn't a numpy array.

Comment: the shape that I am trying to make is images.shape[1], 128, 128, 3)
```
images.shape, labels.shape
((400,) , (400))
images = images.reshape((images.shape[0] * images.shape[1], 128, 128, 3))
```

Comment: @OscarRangel I saw that. Hence my question. `images` is 1-dimensional, yet you access the size of both the first and second dimension (`images.shape[0]`, `images.shape[1]`).

Answer (score 0):

Your `images` array is probably of shape (400,) because the original list doesn't contain all equal shapes. Assuming your pictures/video is in a correct representation in 5D, it would've transformed into a `numpy` array if all the appended items were of the same size. But it didn't. Try:

```
for i in images:
    print(np.array(i.shape))
```

You'll probably find why your list was transformed into an array of lists when you ran this line:

```
images = np.array(images)
```

The `reshape` function only rearranges the current array. Imagine a *2x2x2* cube that has 8 total units. An array can only be reshaped using these 8 units.

As I said, if you find out that not all your picture arrays are the same shape, you won't be able to reshape them to the same shape. You need to either crop, or resize. You can do that with `PIL` and its `Image` module.

```
from PIL import Image

pic = Image.fromarray(pic).resize((128, 128, 3))
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, I see what you mean, so the initial object is a list, and then I create np list, but how I make it into a 128, 128, 3 array so I can train the model.

Comment: Have you made sure that all your pictures _can_ be reshaped to (128, 128, 3)? Or are you looking to resize? Because you used to proper way to turn your list into a `numpy` array, but I suspect some shapes don't match. If shapes don't match, you have to _resize_, not reshape.

Comment: Sorry, I am still learning.... how would you resize? and if I resize, I don't have to do reshape?

Plus it is telling me index out of range.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the post, so I will have to do this for every picture and then store all the images in the np array and I will not need to reshape, right ?

Comment: Exactly. But, if _all_ pictures are of the same shape _and_ can be reshaped to the desired size, reshaping is preferred. I hope you understand the nuance.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a one channel image to three channel image by using

```
image3Channel=np.stack((image1Channel,)*3, -1)
```

Comment: thanks but images=np.stack((images,)*3, -1) does not works....
images.shape
(400, 3)

images = images.reshape((images.shape[0] * images.shape[1], 128, 128, 3))

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1200 into shape (1200,128,128,3)

Comment: you can easily use opencv for that `cv2.resize(image3Channnel, (128,128), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)`

Comment: TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'

Comment: You can change it to `cv2.resize(np.float32(image3Channnel), (128,128), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)`

Comment: image = cv2.resize(np.float32(images), (128,128), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.